# Python Scrapy only scraping the same elements over and over again

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to learn Scrapy and i'm learning on yelp website
this [LINK](https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Restaurants&find_loc=San%20Francisco%2C%20CA&ns=1)
But when scrapy runs, it scrapes the same phone, addresses, over and over again instead of scraping different parts. The selector i have used is all the "li" tags that belong to a specific class for each restaurant of the page each li tag contain each restaurant information i have used appropriate selectors but scrapy gives me results repeated form only 2 or 3 restaurants. For some reason Scrapy is using same parts over and over again when it should skip over them as soon as they are completed in the for loop. *Here is the code*

```
    try:
    import scrapy
    from urlparse import urljoin
except ImportError:
    print "\nERROR IMPORTING THE NESSASARY LIBRARIES\n"

#scrapy.optional_features.remove('boto')

url = raw_input('ENTER THE SITE URL : ')

class YelpSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'yelp spider'
    start_urls = [url]

    def parse(self, response):
        SET_SELECTOR = '.regular-search-result'

        #Going over each li tags containg each resturant belonging to this class

        for yelp in response.css(SET_SELECTOR):

            #getting a slector to get a link to scrape website info from another page
            selector = '.indexed-biz-name a ::attr(href)'

            #getting the complete url joining the extracted part
            momo = urljoin(response.url, yelp.css(selector).extract_first())

            #All the selectors
            name = '.indexed-biz-name a span ::text'
            services = '.category-str-list a ::text'
            address1 = '.neighborhood-str-list ::text'
            address2 = 'address ::text'
            phone = '.biz-phone ::text'

           # extracting them and adding them in a dict 
            try:
                add1 = response.css(address1).extract_first().replace('\n','').replace('\n','')
                add2 = response.css(address2).extract_first().replace('\n','').replace('\n','')
                ADDRESS = add1 + ' ' + add2

                pookiebanana = {

                    "PHONE": response.css(phone).extract_first().replace('\n','').replace('\t',''),
                    "NAME": response.css(name).extract_first().replace('\n','').replace('\t',''),
                    "SERVICES": response.css(services).extract_first().replace('\n','').replace('\t',''),
                    "ADDRESS": ADDRESS,
                }
            except:
                pass

            #Opening another page passing the old dict
            Post = scrapy.Request(momo, callback=self.parse_yelp, meta={'item': pookiebanana})

            #yielding the dict with the website scraped
            yield Post

        #Clicking the next button and recursively calling the same function with the same link
        NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR = '.u-decoration-none.next.pagination-links_anchor  ::attr(href)'
        next_page = response.css(NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR).extract_first()
        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                response.urljoin(next_page),
                callback=self.parse
            )

    def parse_yelp(self, response):
        #Website selector opening a new page from the link we extracted
        WEBSITE_SELECTOR = '.biz-website.js-add-url-tagging a ::text'

        item = response.meta['item']

        #inside the try block extracting the website info and returning the modified dict
        try:
            item['WEBSITE'] = ' '.join(response.css(WEBSITE_SELECTOR).extract_first().split(' '))
        except:
            pass
        return item
```

**i have commented in the code extensively about where i did what. What am i doing wrong ?**

here is the output csv screenshot this shows the repetitions
[image: PICTURE]

HERE is the scrapy scraping output as you can see it scrapes the same thing over and over [image: PIC]
***What is happening and what am i doing wrong ?***

Comment: inside `for yelp` loop you use `response.css` but you should use `yelp.css`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test it but inside `for yelp` loop you should use `yelp.css()` but you use `response.css()`