# Scrapy Spider Returning Same Elements Over and Over

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I've been running into an issue with a spider I've put together. I am trying to scrape individual lines from the transcript on [this site](https://www.thisamericanlife.org/radio-archives/episode/1/transcript/), and have found some appropriate selectors, but when run, the spider's output is simply the same line repeated over and over. I've seen a couple others with similar issues ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43091965/python-scrapy-only-scraping-the-same-elements-over-and-over-again)), but haven't yet found an answer that solves my problem.

(As a note, I believe this may be an issue with my base Python coding and `for` loop building, as opposed to an issue with `scrapy` itself.)

Here is the spider:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class TalSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'tal'
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.thisamericanlife.org/radio-archives/episode/']
    start_urls = ['https://www.thisamericanlife.org/radio-archives/episode/1/transcript/']

def parse(self, response):

    for line in response.xpath('//div'):
        episode_num_text = line.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "radio-wrapper")]/@id').extract()
        radio_date_text = line.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "radio-date")]/text()').extract()
        episode_title = line.xpath('//h2').xpath('a[contains(@href, *)]/text()').extract()
        begin_timestamp = line.xpath('//p[contains(@begin, *)]/@begin').extract()
        speaker_class = line.xpath('//div/@class').extract()
        speaker_name = line.xpath('//h4/text()').extract()
        line_text = line.xpath('//p[contains(@begin, *)]/text()').extract()
        full_audio_link = line.xpath('//p[contains(@class, "full-audio")]/text()').extract()



        for item in zip(episode_num_text, radio_date_text, episode_title, begin_timestamp, speaker_class, speaker_name, line_text, full_audio_link):
            scraped_info = {
                'episode_num_text' : item[0], 
                'radio_date_text' : item[1], 
                'episode_title' : item[2],
                'begin_timestamp' : item[3], 
                'speaker_class' : item[4],
                'speaker_name' : item[5], 
                'line_text' : item[6], 
                'full_audio_link' : item[7],
                }
            yield scraped_info
```

And here is a screen grab of the .csv output
[which shows the repeated output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKRVl.jpg)

The issue seems to lie in the `for` loop. My thinking is this: for each Selector in this list of Selectors, pull a subset that element as defined by the items in the for loop. Instead, it seems to be executing: for each of the 177 Selectors in this list, return the first element of each of the items defined.

I'm happy to clarify any of these issues, and would greatly appreciate any help anyone can offer!

Comment: You just need to start your xpath expressions inside the loop with a dot making them context-specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please be aware of the absolute XPath versus [relative XPath](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#working-with-relative-xpaths) in the Scrapy.

When parsing, you are looping over the elements parsed from an absolute XPath. However, inside the loop, you are still using absolute XPath, which is wrong and should be relative XPath.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this, this definitely helped!